# How to install AUR package in home directory?

Tags: aur, makepkg

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate is not available as an Arch Linux core package, and has a built-in upgrade mechanism. For these reasons it would be convenient to install it into my home directory, letting it upgrade itself without needing to rebuild the AUR package or running anything as root. Is this possible?

As far as I can tell from the PKGBUILD it refers to a `pkgdir` variable, but I can't find any `makepkg` flags to control it and `export pkgdir="${HOME}/bin"` doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

### Your plan is not recommended

Have a look at the [File Hirarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) page. You should never let `pacman` write to files in `$HOME`. This directory fully belongs to the user. `pacman` manages files in e.g. `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib` and you should never manually change files there.

### pacman installs files, not makepkg

`makepkg` copies files from `srcdir` to `pkgdir`. Typically this means `make DSTDIR=$pkgdir install` or similar. After that `makepkg` creates a `tar` file from the `pkgdir` directory.

`pacman` installs the content of the `tar` file to `--root` or `--sysroot` but both should not be used to install software to a custom directory.

### What you can do

You could use `makepkg` to copy the files to `$HOME/bin` by changing the `package()` function in your `PKGBUILD`. This is what you describe in the question but I would rather let `makepkg` create a package and manually copy the content of the `pkg` directory to `$HOME/.local/{bin,?}`. Now you are sure that all needed files are installed and you still own all files in `$HOME`.

If you want that this package is in the pacman database, you could make an empty dummy package, that tracks dependencies and stops you from installing conflicting packages. You could change the `package()` function so that it only installs a text file with a comment.

## Don't do that

Make the `package()` function install files to `$pkgdir/home/you/bin` and install the package with `pacman`.

Comment: That sounds like it's not at all a supported operation. Is that right? I'm not sure what to make of "Maybe you could make an empty dummy package to install dependencies."